# Querying for FireStore docs in a loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've seen some other people post this question and I have tried the solutions they said work, however nothing has worked for me thus far.

I am querying from a single collection (A) and getting an array of documents, then I want to go through each of the docs in the array and query from another collection (B) based on a value in each doc from the first collection (A).

Here is my code, I have tried both `async/await` (shown in this example) as well `.then` with `Promise.all()`

```
export const getUserEvents = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  console.log("getUserEvents:req.params.userId: ", req.params.userId);

  try {
    let events: Event[] = [];
    const snapshot = await db.collection("eventPeople").where("userId", "==", req.params.userId).get();
    snapshot.forEach(async (doc) => {
      const eventRef = await db.collection("events").where("eventId", "==", doc.data().eventId).get();

      eventRef.forEach((eventDoc) => {
        console.log("event: ", eventDoc.data())
      });
    });

    console.log("events: ", events)

    return res.json({ events: events });
  } catch (err) {
    functions.logger.error("unable to query eventPeople using userId", { userId: req.params.userId, error: err });
  }

  return res.json({ events: "events" });
};
```

Comment: What happens now when you run your code? Are you only returning the eventDoc document results or some combination of the two queries?

Comment: @Brettski it had just been printing unresolved promises

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`forEach` closers don't expect an `async` function, so the `await` insode that loop doesn't make the code around the `forEach` wait for anything.

To make the entire loop wait, use `for of`:

```
for (const doc of snapshot.docs) {
  const eventRef = await db.collection("events").where("eventId", "==", doc.data().eventId).get();

  eventRef.forEach((eventDoc) => {
    console.log("event: ", eventDoc.data())
  });
}
```

Also see: [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)

Comment: Didn't realize that about `forEach`, thanks this worked.